# How to get Max output from a while loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that shows what the max amount of money was in the while loop and I'm completely lost as to how I would do that. I know that the 'Max' function exists but I'm not super sure how to implement it

```
import random

count=0
number=0
money_in_pot = (float(input('Enter amount of money you want to put in pot ')))
while money_in_pot > 0:    
    dice_roll = random.randint(1, 7), random.randint(1, 7) 
    print (dice_roll)
    roll = sum(dice_roll)
    count+=1
    if roll == 7:
        money_in_pot += 4 
        print ('You rolled a 7')
    else:
        money_in_pot -= 1
        print ('You did not roll a 7')
print ('You are out of money in', count, 'turn/s')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add variable (`max_amount`) which will store value of `money_in_pot` and update it when roll is **7** and current amount more then initial:

```
import random

count = 0
number = 0
money_in_pot = float(input('Enter amount of money you want to put in pot: '))
max_amount = money_in_pot  # store initial value
while money_in_pot > 0:
    dice_roll = random.randint(1, 7), random.randint(1, 7)
    print(dice_roll)
    roll = sum(dice_roll)
    count += 1
    if roll == 7:
        money_in_pot += 4
        if money_in_pot > max_amount:  # update max if it more then before
            max_amount = money_in_pot
        print ('You rolled a 7.')
    else:
        money_in_pot -= 1
        print ('You did not roll a 7.')
print ('You are out of money in {} turn/s. Max amount was: {}.'.format(count, max_amount))
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it figured out now

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a maximum_value variable and adding a condition like so:

```
if money_in_pot > maximum_value:
    maximum_value=money_in_pot
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you use the variable `max_value` for it:

```
...
    if roll == 7:
        money_in_pot += 4 
        max_value = max(max_value, money_in_pot)
        print ('You rolled a 7')
...
```

Never using python much but you can write it eventually shorter like this:

```
...
    if roll == 7:
        max_value = max(max_value, money_in_pot += 4)
        print ('You rolled a 7')
...
```